# video file downloads with no file type? javascript

Tags: javascript, file, types

Is there any way to force it to download as what it is, an MP4?

Clearly the file type is not set on the server but I am wondering if there is a clean way to tell JavaScript it is an MP4. So far I have tried just about everything under the sun. Any way of doing it no matter how difficult would be great.

```
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href =url;
                link.type='video/mp4';
                link.download = 'videodfdf.mp4';
                link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

The thing is, I am creating a *YouTube Downloader*. So far everything is working but I am trying to avoid having to stream every YouTube video from my server directly. This is the difference between me paying `£5` a month to host my site and something like `£30`